# Groups not getting created when subsite is created powershell csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I am creating subsite through powershell script csom. Subsite is getting created but not sharepoint groups under subsite. what could be the reason?Please respond

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to break the role inheritence for the subsite. This post describes how to do this using CSOM: https://www.morgantechspace.com/2016/04/break-permission-inheritance-in-sharepoint-csom.html

Answer (score 0):

If select unique permission， then it needs to also write csom code to create the group, it will not create group automatically:

```
 class Program  
    {  


     private class Configuration  
        {  
                public static string ServiceSiteUrl = "https:// https://gowthamr.sharepoint.com";  
                public static string ServiceUserName = "gkm@gowthamr.onmicrosoft.com";  
                public static string ServicePassword = "xxxxxxxxxx";  
        }  

          static ClientContext GetonlineContext()  
               {  
        var securePassword = new SecureString();  
        foreach (char c in Configuration.ServicePassword)  
        {  
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);  
        }  
    var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Configuration.ServiceUserName, securePassword);  
    var context = new ClientContext(Configuration.ServiceSiteUrl);  
    context.Credentials = onlineCredentials;  
    return context;  
                   }  

        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            var ClientContext=GetonlineContext();  
            Web web = clientContext.Web;             
            GroupCreationInformation groupCreationInfo = new GroupCreationInformation();  
            groupCreationInfo.Title = "Gowtham_Group";  
            groupCreationInfo.Description="Custom Group Created...";  
            User owner = web.EnsureUser(@"XXXXXX");  
            User member = web.EnsureUser(@"YYYYYY");   
            Group group = web.SiteGroups.Add(groupCreationInfo);  
            group.Owner = owner;  
            group.Users.AddUser(member);  
            group.Update();     
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();             
        }  
    }
```

Reference:
[Create Group In SharePoint 2013 Online Using CSOM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-group-in-sharepoint-2013-online-using-csom/)